# How to drywall a concrete footing

Tags: drywall, concrete, basement

I am working on a house built in 1960 that has a supporting wall in the basement which is on a concrete footing. I am ready to put up drywall, and am unsure how I should drywall over the footing?

Possibly seal the concrete and then glue the drywall directly on the concrete?

Or add some furring strips to build out the wall over the concrete?

Below is an image of the footing from the side and then from above. The footing sticks out a bit in some spots, I could try and make this flush with the wall or its another reason to build out the wall.

Looking for some advice on which direction to take and/or a concrete sealer that would work well in this situation. I'm in a cold weather climate if that makes a difference...

[image: Concrete Footing]
[image: Concrete Footing from above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That footing isn't that big.  You glue it on.   It isn't that big of a deal.   The big deal is grinding out the protrusions.   You don't deal with those and the bottom of your wall is going to look pretty wonky.

I would run the drywall until may 2" above grade - give yourself some room for moisture and know that your flooring will take you up at least 1/2".   Tack on 4"+ trim (pine is my choice for basements)and it looks like you will have only 2-3" on the concrete with the trim going up over most of the concrete (meaning you will be gluing your trim on but that is a different question).

Comment: I agree, don't take the drywall all the way to the floor, use a baseboard to cover the footing. Assuming there are appliances in the basement, any leaks or burst pipes will not mean replacing the drywall.